# How to setup my UWP project with Xamarin.Forms and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution using MvvmCross. I have the Android project working correctly with it. I want to add a UWP project to use with my Forms project, but I can not find any documentation on how I can create a UWP project with my Forms and MvvmCross setup.

Comment: You can check [Xamarin Forms Setup Windows Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/) and the [MvvmCross Forms UWP Playground Project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/6.2.0/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp) to see what changed you need to add for your project to work

Comment: The playground project helped a lot. I posted the complete answer for anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MvvmCross Forms UWP Playground Project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/6.2.0/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp) helped a lot, great for any fundamentals. Here is the solution for anyone else that wants it:

Change App.xaml to

```
<local:MyApp
    x:Class="MyApp.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Forms.UWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

</local:MyApp>
```

And in App.xaml.cs:

```
sealed partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public abstract class MyApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<Core.App, Forms.App>, Core.App, Forms.App, MainPage>
{
}
```

And MainPage.xaml:

```
<mvxf:MvxFormsWindowsPage
    xmlns:mvxf="using:MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views"
    x:Class="MyApp.Forms.UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Forms.UWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</mvxf:MvxFormsWindowsPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```